# VBA - Searching specific value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

Will do my best to explain problem.

In column A I have i.p. addresses and I want to know if those exact values are located in column B, ie if value 192.168.6.1 from column A is present in column B. The problem is that some of the cells in column B have multiple i.p. addresses separated by semicolon, ie 10.198.80.71; 10.198.81.71; 192.168.6.1.

Search values

[image: Search values]

I was thinking about creating VBA function that will temporarily separate values and search for the exact one. Then I would execute function in cell and it will show true/false. However, I'm not sure how to write the code.

Sheet name is shcheck and its now a table.

Hope it makes sense. Happy to provide further details.

Comment: Can you post your sample data with [Markdown](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) formatting?

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS` with wildcards.

Comment: Try: `=AND(A2<>"",COUNT(FIND("; "&A2&"; ","; "&B$2:B$20&"; "))>0)`.

Comment: If you're unsure how to write VBA code, try splitting the data with `TEXTSPLIT`, then use `MATCH` on the separated columns. You could put the `TEXTSPLIT` formula on another sheet, and record a macro to do it automatically as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub find_string()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("A2:A8")
        For Each c In rng
        Set a = Range("B:B").Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
            If Not a Is Nothing Then
                c.Offset(0, 2).Value = "True"
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```